# Need way to parse the Protection table using P4.net DLL

Tags: p4.net

I too need a way to find out, how to get and parse the protection table using the P4.net DLL. I am trying to run "p4 protects" command using P4.Net DLL. I just need a way to find out which AD Group has access to which branch of perforce tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code

P4Form group = p4.Parse_Form("group", groupString);

groupString is a string argument that will be written filling all the required fields of a group.